# Python: Will os.getcwd() necessarily return a realpath?

Tags: python, os.path

Is the following **always** a correct statement?

```
os.getcwd() == os.path.realpath(os.getcwd())
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

At least in CPython, yes. There is even a [test](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb3e0c240bc60fe08d332ff5955d54197f79751c/Lib/test/test_posixpath.py#L329) for this in Python source code

Comment: I wonder if this is true for something like HFS+, which allowed hard links to directories. I no longer have any HFS+ file systems to check.

Comment: @chepner in this scenario, realpath will be different, too